# Forgotten animated movie involves encasing things in "gluestick"

Tags: identify-this-movie, animation

I'm trying to remember an animated film I saw as a child, but the details are so fuzzy I only remember for certain these following details:

1. The movie was definitely animated. I'm fairly certain it was 2d and it was older-- ie, 90's or earlier. When I was a kid but while most cartoons aside from Saturday morning and The Disney Afternoon were rerun from earlier decades (and I didn't have the Disney Channel). I highly doubt it was original programming.
2. The antagonist was trying encase everything in "gluestick." This amounted to everything being frozen in solid clear cubes.
3. The antagonist's intentions were good; he was just trying to protect things but was too stupid/deluded to realize how bad his idea actually was.

I think also that it was a Christmas movie, that the protagonist was a girl and that the antagonist was a wolf or something. I just seem to remember presents being frozen in the "gluestick," and something about how the antagonist was just trying to keep children from breaking their toys.

So yeah basically a cartoon wolf tries to save Christmas by making toys unbreakable, without realizing that his process renders them impossible to play with. I think he accidentally "gluesticks" the little girl before realizing his mistake. I want to say it was a Chuck Jones film from the 70's but that might just be the memories of How the Grinch Stole Christmas creeping in.

Comment: Welcome to M&TV SE. This question has plot details and release year. That's nice. However, do you remember other plot details, language, country, anything at all? Please add them, so that it can help identify this movie. Also see [How to ask Identify-this-X questions](http://movies.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: Sounded like The Lego Movie :)

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It *was* Chuck Jones. You're looking for [Raggedy Ann and Andy in The Great Santa Claus Caper](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Raggedy_Ann_and_Andy_in_The_Great_Santa_Claus_Caper) (1978).

> **Inventor and efficiency expert Alexander Graham Wolf, who looks and sounds like Wile E. Coyote, is planning to take over Santa's workshop.** Overhearing this, Comet, one of Santa's reindeer, asks Raggedy Ann, Raggedy Andy, and their dog Raggedy Arthur to help her because they're easy to carry and aren't bothered by cold weather.
>
> **At the factory, Alexander is using a machine to encase all the toys in blocks of a transparent and unbreakable substance called gloopstik (made by ACME), to ensure that they'll last forever** (even though the children won't be able to play with them). He then intends to charge the children for the gloopstik-encased toys and become rich.

Here are the first 9 minutes:

Comment: Gloopstick > gluestick. So funny, so relatable.

Comment: Amazing. I completely forgot about the Raggedy Ann branding but I could always remember those cutesy pursed lips Chuck Jones loved to draw everyone with. Now I have one less unresolved memory distracting me thank you!